# Synonym of bad effect or bad situation - one word

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I want to use a noun to describe the bad effects of AIDS on the population of a country. The context of the word is this sentence:

> In this report, we also provide some statistics on the **bad effects**
>   of AIDS on the population.

However, it seems that **bad effects**  are not the appropriate words.

Comment: Do you strictly need a one word solution, or is a suitable replacement for 'bad effects' good?  "adverse effects", "negative impacts", etc would all be perfectly reasonable in the given context.

Comment: I thought of that, but the use of some word to mean 'negative' could be used to emphasize, rather than imply there are positives.

Comment: "...the *catastrophic consequences* Aids has had on the population. This is quite an extreme expression  and perhaps too emotive for a report but depending on the statistics it might very well be accurate.

Comment: *Blight*. *Bummer*.

Comment: Nonsense. There was nothing linguistically wrong with the example, even if you or your mentor thought some kind of political correctness more important.

If you think "bad effects are not the appropriate words" then why not take the trouble to explain why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find five alternatives to "bad effects on," with three different meanings, depending on what you prefer to say:

- **detriment to,** the opposite of *benefit to.*
- **injury of** or, better, **harm to.**
- **menace against** or, better, **threat to.**

Of the five, *injury* probably does not work in your specific sentence, because it wants to repeat the word *of*, which the sentence already uses for another purpose.  (There may exist alternate ways to reword your sentence entirely to evade the question and achieve an even more pleasing effect, but this is not what you have asked.)

Answer (score 3):

I find seven alternatives to "bad effects on," with three different meanings, depending on what you prefer to say:

Problems, consequences, downsides, negatives, drawbacks, disadvantages, damages.

Edit: Adding "Fallout"

Comment: agua, do you have another? I ask because observed that you missed to type the full stop at the end of that 'sentence'.

Comment: Elbe, could you explain why this answer is not helpful?

Comment: Downvoter - any constructive criticism?

Comment: Elberich Schneider offered you a good explanation. Your answer is a series of words some of which are worthy, others much less so. For example, *disadvantages*, which implies there are also positive aspects. But I strongly doubt anyone could suggest that there are any advantages to having AIDS.

Comment: Rather than downvoting it would have been more constructive to comment on my answer to improve it.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps **[devastation](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/devastation)**

> severe and widespread destruction or damage

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [harm](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/harm)

For example:

> The products are often rejected by watchdogs because of the potential harm to the environment.